# Drop down Combobox inside datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I've been struggling with this problem for too long now, I've seen all the answers on the subject and though I've found several none of them seems to work for me. So the base of my problem is as follows: I have a `DataGridView` that will add a row to itself once another `DataGridView` cell is double clicked. When this `DataGridView`gets the row added, it adds 2 types of columns to itself one is a `ComboBox`, which supposedly has a collection already set in it (just went to the `ComboBox` options inside the datagrid and filled up its collection) and a check box column, now both of them do nothing once I click on them, double click, multiple click as many clicks as you want but nothing happens. I've even tried the following code.

```
public static void combolist(DataGridView combogrid)            
{
            
    var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    DataTable data = new DataTable();

    data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
    data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

    data.Rows.Add("item1");
    data.Rows.Add("item2");
    data.Rows.Add("item3");

    column.DataSource = data;
    column.ValueMember = "Value";
    column.DisplayMember = "Description";

    combogrid.Columns.Add(column); 
}
```

and even though I can add a new column of the type `ComboBox` to my `DataGridView` it is still empty(or appears to be since I can't click to see a drop down list). my data `DataGridView` gridview properties are set to:

> editMode:editOnEnter, readOnly:false.

Is there something I'm missing here? Why can't I populate or display this `ComboBox`? This problem is driving me crazy, and I believe this is the best site to find an answer. I would really much appreciate it... a lot.

Ok so I definitely need to see the problem from another perspective, I've even tried binding the `ComboBox` to a datasource and still doesn't display anything!, even though the same datasource binded to a normal `ComboBox` gets the desired result

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(combogrid.Rows[0].Cells[2]);

ComboColumn.DataSource = class.details.GetData();
ComboColumn.DisplayMember = "name";
```

is there some basic step I'm missing when working with `ComboBox`inside `DataGridView`?

Comment: I don't see a mistake in the given informations and I don't know something special you should consider since the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` is almost the same as a usual `ComboBox`. Maybe you could post the whole code for adding the rows/columns and the other stuff of the `DataGridView` which is related to this operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. I've tested your code as posted with visual studio 2012 and executing the code by click on a `Button` having an empty `DataGridView`. It worked for me, because I got a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` having a `ComboBox` with three empty entries. I extended the code as below and got three named entries:

   ```
       data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
       data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

       data.Rows.Add("item1");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Value", "value1");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Description", "description1");
       data.Rows.Add("item2");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Value", "value2");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Description", "description2");
       data.Rows.Add("item3");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Value", "value3");
       data.Rows[data.Rows.Count - 1].SetField("Description", "description3");

       column.DataSource = data;
   ```

   It seems that your code just adds a row named "item1/2/3" or a row that just got the first column  ("Value" which is not your displayvalue) filled with the given value to the datatable having no  values which could be displayed. In the end I couldn't reproduce your problem of not being able to  open the dropdownlist (notice that I used a empty `DataGridView` because I don't know what else you  have in your `DataGridView`).
2. I don't know if the posted code is exactly that code where you have trouble with. But you write that you add a row to your `DataGridView` when a cell is clicked and that when this happen you add two columns. Do you mean you add for each added row two columns to the grid or do you just mean that the row consists of this two columns?
   If the last one is right it seems to me to be a similar problem as with the posted code. Did you consider to create the row manually with adding a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` and `DataGridViewCheckboxCell`? We have a quiet complicated `DataGridViewUserControl` where we dynamically add different celltypes and have no problems with getting them displayed correctly. But we do create all Rows manually, filling the wished cell-types by hand into the rows and do not specify a type for a column.

Comment: Im sorry ive seem to confused u with my explenation. Here is the thing, the datagrid2 is an empty datagrid that gets a row added to it with 2 columns once the event cellclick on datagrid1 is triggered, the rows with column types apear to be added in the proper way but no colections are found in the combobox column(column1) and also nothing happens when clicking the checkbox button column2. I guess the best way will be to add all columns programaticaly but im not quite sure why im having this problem, thx for ur answer buddy

Answer (score 2):

You are adding 2 columns to the datatable, and filling up only the value member. Try this

```
        var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
        data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

        data.Rows.Add("item1","123");
        data.Rows.Add("item2","234");
        data.Rows.Add("item3","245");

        column.DataSource = data;
        column.ValueMember = "Value";
        column.DisplayMember = "Description";

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

Comment: thx for ur answer, but i still get the same outcome even with this modifications

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `DataTable` has `2 columns`. But you add only values for cells at column `1`, the cells at column 2 (which will be used as `DisplayMember` of your `comboBox`) have empty values. Try this instead:

```
//.....
data.Rows.Add("item1","This is Item1");
data.Rows.Add("item2","This is Item2");
data.Rows.Add("item3","This is Item3");
//.....
```

Comment: i apreciate ur answer but even changing this there is no diference, i think the problem recides in the fact the combo seems not to be responding to any clic event i make or anything althoug i dont understand why this would happen

Comment: @user2793090 sorry, **I tested it**

Comment: there must be something im setting wrong in my datagrid then, some property, because i made the changes u sugest and i still get the same result... any thoughts?